# How can I print the list of groups in just one line with commas between them?

Tags: bash, shell

for example this script gives me the list of groups but each group is in a line

```
for group in `groups`                                                                                                   do
        echo "$group,"

done
```

The objective is to put them like this :group1,group2,group3.
Instead of :

```
group1,
group2,
group3
```

Comment: When you call `groups` without the for loop, what is your output? Each group on a new line, or with spaces in between?

Answer (score 3):

So just replace spaces with comma.

```
groups | tr ' ' ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another simple alternative is to use `sed` and a global substitution of `' '` with `',`', e.g.

```
groups | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash by locally changing IFS to a comma:

```sh
join() { local IFS=$1; shift; echo "$*"; }
join , $(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling another program with

```
my_group=$(groups)
echo "${my_group// /,}"
```